# Which java web framework to use for google app engine development in 2012?

Tags: google-app-engine, tapestry, click-framework

I am looking at developing simple java web-app to be deployed on GAE and learn about Java web development in the process. I am not inclined to use RIA component-based frameworks like Wicket and Vaadin.

I have looked at Play 2.0, Tapestry 5 and Click, out of which Play 2.0 cannot be used on GAE (and I don't want to put efforts in learning Play 1.0 which is a thing of the past). I have no problem in using Javascript for client-side programming. So, I am not considering GWT.

I have read up some documentation. Click seems to be easy to deploy on GAE. But, Tapestry 5 seems like a good framework to study and learn and become a better software/web developer. But, my google search for using Tapestry with GAE yielded pages that talked about hacks to get it working on GAE instead of having a first-class support for GAE itself.

I do not mind putting in efforts to learn a complex framework if it is going to make me a better programmer. Does anyone have any experience with using Tapestry on GAE? Or should I just go for Click?

Comment: I wrote a GAE app in Scala, Scalatra, LiftJson, Objectify (ORM), Guice, and Specs2. This let me write Sinatra-style REST endpoints without a lot of complexity. The front-end was just a JS/PHP site on shared hosting. This avoided GAE costs for web traffic, let GAE do the heavy lifting, and was pretty snappy. Overall development was pretty painless.

Comment: @BenManes, thanks a lot for offering an interesting alternative. Scalatra looks great and well-documented, which is very important for a newbie like me. Since you used different packages, did you face any integration issues? What I am afraid of is running into some integration issues later.

Comment: UI integration was easy since its just REST endpoints, so routes and json. That meant discovering bugs not found by tests and iterating on the api as the front-end was flushed out. For server-side I found GAE frustrating as not having friendly APIs (low-level, brittle, and not Java idiomatic). The maven/gradle plugins make releasing a breeze. Injection + mocks makes testing simple if you have an api/services/etc separation.

Comment: @BenManes, looks like implementing REST services using lean web frameworks is the way to go for modern web-development. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In 2012 if you are serious about web development you need to use both server side and client side frameworks.

Here's what I recommend:

1. Server-side: use something that gives you both HTML generation and REST/JSON support in one package. For Java a natural choice is [JAX-RS standard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_API_for_RESTful_Web_Services). I use [RESTEasy](http://www.jboss.org/resteasy) with [HtmlEasy](http://code.google.com/p/htmleasy/), where you can choose your template lib of choice. I recommend [Silken](https://github.com/codedance/silken).
2. Client-side. Since you are java dev I recommend GWT. It's awesome. Just DO NOT use it's Widgets or UiBinder. Use pure HTML (it's generated on server, right) and then add code via [GwtQuery](http://code.google.com/p/gwtquery/). Also [avoid GWT-RPC](http://www.zackgrossbart.com/hackito/antiptrn-gwt2/) or RequestFactory, go with REST ([GETResty](http://restygwt.fusesource.org/index.html) or [SpiffyUI](http://www.spiffyui.org/)).

Comment: Actually, I am not that experienced in Java web development. A lot of what you mentioned is new to me. Thanks a lot for your answer. I thought I can learn one web framework and be done with it. But, it looks like, as always , there is a lot to learn :)

Comment: Peter, could you suggest some nice tutorials about RESTEasy. The information available on JBOSS site is underwhelming. Do we have automatic HTML generation for Jersey?

Comment: Hi Peterm, I would like to understand better your comment.
Because I think that if you do not use Widgets, UiBinder, GWT-RPC or RequestFactory, you are not also using  EventBus or Activity/Place and so on. Furthermore if the libraries you suggested are only porting of Javascript you risk to lose the end-to-end debugging process.
I see the advantages of REST API, but on client side I prefer to use GWT plain because I do not want to lose the control and the optimization factors of GWT. What are you using of awesome of GWT?

Comment: @Salil: http://www.mkyong.com/tutorials/jax-rs-tutorials/

Comment: @ungarida: you can use MVP, EventBus, etc, without Widgets, that's what I do. The part I like about GWT is that I write Java and GWT produces highly optimized Javascript.

Comment: any recommendations for year 2015 now?

Comment: vue.js on client side, RESTEasy on server side for REST-JSON. For html generation/templating on both server+client side use https://mustache.github.io/. It needs a tiny glue code to work with RestEasy.