# GWT modules are different from Google App Engine Modules, right?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jakarta-ee, gwt

I'm trying to develop a web-based user interface for a Google App Engine application.  The Google App Engine application uses [Google Modules](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/modules/).  I've [read from other users that GWT is a good choice for the user interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11877299/which-java-web-framework-to-use-for-google-app-engine-development-in-2012).  I've also had experience with GWT from the [Google Plugin for Eclipse](https://developers.google.com/eclipse/).

I suspect that a [Google Module](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/modules/) conforms to a J2EE convention of modules.  I found a site that says there are [4 types of J2EE modules](http://dev.fyicenter.com/Interview-Questions/J2EE-1/What_are_the_four_types_of_J2EE_modules_.html).

**QUESTION 1**

What's the difference between a [GWT Module](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideOrganizingProjects.html#DevGuideModules) and a [Google Module](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/modules/)?  Is there ANY relationship?  I suspect no.

**QUESTION 2**

Is there any relationship between any of the [4 types of J2EE modules](http://dev.fyicenter.com/Interview-Questions/J2EE-1/What_are_the_four_types_of_J2EE_modules_.html) and [GWT Module](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideOrganizingProjects.html#DevGuideModules)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**QUESTION 1**

No, there's no relationship between a GWT module and App Engine modules.

A GWT Module are XML files that will give instructions to the GWT compiler. Remember that GWT compiles Java code to Javascript to be ran in your browser.

An App Engine Module is the answer to the problem of executing multiple runtimes (JVM, Python, Golang, etc) on a single App Engine application. Before App Engine Modules, developers needed to choose a single runtime for their application. Now, each App Engine module can use different runtime.

**QUESTION 2**

No, there's no relationship between a GWT module and any J2EE module.

J2EE Modules (war, jar, ear files) are meant to be deployed in application servers (Tomcat, Jetty, etc). This has nothing to do with the GWT compiler.